# all browser redirect to notfound.name if login to wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, browser

i need your help

my all browser (chrome, firefox, opera) if i try login to wp-admin redirect to web notfound.name

https://notfound.name/?e=404&u=Mpac6OY7rakNAuwqPIsrAyxnUwKdOILoXPFkZdRiCeJx1su09hC35R6TBumBaf8sAYP8st%2BCgG2NUvKH4t5jnw%3D%3D&s=https%3A%2F%2Fvenue-files.locatise.io%2Fclusters%2F26%2Fstarter.js%3Fe%3D1d0cb1

[image]

I have tried installing Malwarebyte software, found 3 malware and i deleted, but not work redirect again to web notfound.name

i'm stuck and i don't know what else to do

please help me

thanks before